# Modify property from ViewModel before binding to ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I am binding `ItemSource` to a `ListView` using Prism MVVM. This is list `Cell`

```
<ListView x:Name="list1" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  
                       Text="{Binding StudentName}" />
                <Button x:Name="mybtn"         
                    BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference list1}, Path=BindingContext}" 
                    Command="{Binding BtnTextCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference mybtn}}"  
                    Text="{Binding BtnText}" />
            </StackLayout>                  
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This is Source in `ViewModel`

```
private List<Student> _studentList;
public List<Student> StudentList
{
    get { return _studentList; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _studentList, value); }
}
```

I want to modify Button `Text` every time for each list item before binding. How can I do it from `ViewModel` Class to get updated value for `BtnText`?

Modifying values means if `Text` has ID `value` then show 'Present' if null then show 'Absent' etc.

Student Class

```
public class Student
{
    public Mychildren MyKid { get; set; }
    public string LocalStudentId { get; set; }
    public int? StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int? AttendanceTypeStatusId { get; set; }
    public int? StudentDailyAttendanceId { get; set; }
    public int? AbsentReasonId { get; set; }
    public string AttendanceTypeStatusCD { get; set; }}
}
```

**Edit:**

I have written this logic in Converter, throwing exception in first `else` part at `value`

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    string attStatusId = string.Empty;
    //AttendanceTypeStatusId
    if (value != null)
    {
        attStatusId = "Present";
    }
    else
    {
        attStatusId = SISConst.AttendanceResults.FirstOrDefault(i => i.AttendanceTypeStatusID == System.Convert.ToInt32(value)).AttendanceTypeStatusCD;
    }
    if (attStatusId == "Absent")
    {
        return "A";
    }
    else if (attStatusId == "Present")
    {
        return "P";
    }
    else
    {
        return "L";
    }
}
```

ExcpetionScreenshot

[image]

Comment: Maybe create a new model called BindableModel and populate the ListView using this model, in that model assign the values based on your conditions?

Comment: Have you taken a look at value converters? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

Comment: What's the purpose of `ButtonTextHold`? Either remove it or raise `PropertyChanged` for `ButtonText`, too, when changing `ButtonTextHold`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your `Student` model must contain an ID property. Do you mean you want to set the button's text to Present when ID's value isn't null and set it to Absent on the other hand?

If so, you should not change the Button's Binding Context. You could only change the command's source when you want to fire this command in your view model instead of the Student model. Here is my XAML for you referring to:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <local:IDToStringConverter x:Key="IDToStringConverter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="list1" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                Text="{Binding StudentName}" />
                            <Button x:Name="mybtn"         
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.BtnTextCommand, Source={x:Reference list1}}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference mybtn}}"  
                                Text="{Binding ID, Converter={x:StaticResource IDToStringConverter}}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The converter implement the effect that returns different strings depending on ID's value:

```
public class IDToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            return "Present";
        }
        return "Absent";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Updated:**

If you want to store some data at runtime, you could create a static class:

```
public static class UtiClass
{
    public static List<AttendanceStatusModel> AttendanceStatus { set; get; }
}
```

Set its value before you push to page 2: `UtiClass.AttendanceStatus = //...`. Then you could access it anywhere else after that setting. i.e. in your converter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please check my updated question and description too.

Comment: @Arvindraja As I said above, there's no need to handle the code in your view model. Bind your button's text directly to your `AttendanceTypeStatusId`. Then manipulate it in the converter. Return whatever you want there. And I think you should do it like that as each item has its own `AttendanceTypeStatusId`, you can't place the logic in the view model.

Comment: I have `AttendanceStatus` `List`, Can you pl tell me what is a good way to get list data in converter class. I mean where to call service to get `AttendanceStatus` data?

Comment: @Arvindraja What is `AttendanceStatus` used for? Where did you place that list?

Comment: This list has only two fields `AttendanceTypeStatusID` and `AttendanceTypeStatusCD` from this list, based on ID I am getting Text like Absent, Present, Late etc. I always has three records with Id's.

Comment: @Arvindraja How did you retrieve this `AttendanceStatus` list? If it is a static resource, make it as a static property of a static class then access it in your converter.

Comment: As of now I was getting  `AttendanceStatus` data in Page1(Inside gotoPage2 button click event). When moving to page2,  I was passing this data using Navigationparam and collecting on page2. This is not static. Different for different logins. Sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: Can you please check my update. I am getting null reference exception.

Comment: @Arvindraja How did you bind your button's Text? Here my code is `Text="{Binding ID, Converter={x:StaticResource IDToStringConverter}}"`, it means the value in the converter is ID. You must make sure it is not a null value otherwise this error occurs. I think you could try my code to see the effect: `if (value != null)
        {
            return "Present";
        }
        return "Absent";`

Answer (score 2):

A [Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) would be a good solution for this. Easy to create and modify.

Try something like -

```
<ListView x:Name="list1" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  
                       Text="{Binding StudentName}" />
                <Button x:Name="mybtn"         
                    BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference list1}, Path=BindingContext}" 
                    Command="{Binding BtnTextCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference mybtn}}"  
                    Text="{Binding PresentBool, Converter={StaticResource PresentToString}}" />
            </StackLayout>                  
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then create a new class that implements [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.ivalueconverter?view=xamarin-forms) -

```
public class PresentToString : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)value ? "Present" : "Absent";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

To use it as a StaticResource as I have above, you'll need to include it in a relevant resource dictionary. You can put it on the Page/ContentView that this ListView is from -

```
<ContentView>
    <ContentView.Resources>
        <PresentToString x:Key="PresentToString" />
    </ContentView.Resources>

    <ListView x:Name="list1" ... >
...
```

And that should be all! If your converter is in a difference namespace, you will have to add the xaml include to the Page/ContentView.

**EDIT**

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var typedValue = (int)value;
    // Since ints are not nullable, we don't need to do a null check

    switch (typedValue)
    {
        case 1:
            return "P";
        case 2:
            return "L";
        // case 0 handled in default. Removed to avoid redundancy.
        default:
            return "A";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have kind of complicated logic to manipulate values. If you would like to see it, I'll update my question with ViewModel.

Comment: I'm assuming your "Student" class has some kind of boolean or way to figure out if a student is absent or not. As long as your values are bound properly, the view should update accordingly.

Comment: In Edit2 above, I'm not sure what you mean by "throwing exception in first else part at value". I assume this could be a typing issue because `value` is an `object` and you are comparing it to `strings`. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Still I am getting exception. Pl see screenshot attached in my question.

Comment: You should be able to remove that line altogether. As to why it is null, that must be a binding issue from the XAML code. Double check your XAML and post a screenshot if you can't find anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question properly, the standard way to do that is to create another get only property which returns Present or Absent conditionally, and then raise property changed event for that custom property when the actual property is changed.